# SnapView in Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8

I want to add SnapView and want to handle all screen resolutions in my blank grid app in Windows 8 , how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Check **Step 3** of this tutorial [Hello World Windows Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215600.aspx)